# Adding ChangeListener to javafx textfield to get focus information in scala

Tags: scala, javafx

I tried to add a ChangeListener to a TextField but I get an error.

Here is the Example I tried

```
class MyTextField() extends TextField
{

  val change: javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener[Boolean] = new TextFieldChangeListener
  focusedProperty().addListener(change)

  class TextFieldChangeListener extends ChangeListener[Boolean] 
  {
    override def changed(arg0: ObservableValue[_ <: Boolean], oldPropertyValue: Boolean, newPropertyValue: Boolean) 
    {
       println("Fokus")
    }
 }
}
```

And these are the packages I've imported

```
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener
import javafx.scene.control.TextField
```

But I get the following error in eclipse:

```
overloaded method value addListener with alternatives: (x$1: 
javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener[_ >: java.lang.Boolean])Unit <and>    
(x$1:javafx.beans.InvalidationListener)Unit cannot be applied to    
(javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener[scala.Boolean])
```

The reason might be the `scala.Boolean` and `java.lang.Boolean` but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: "The reason might be the scala.Boolean and java.lang.Boolean but I'm not sure about this." yes it is

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `Boolean` means `java.lang.Boolean` (if there are no imports saying otherwise). In Scala, it means `scala.Boolean`. `focusedProperty()`, being a JavaFX method, obviously can't know anything about `scala.Boolean`.